# Unable to access a the variable on another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this class attached to a `PauseButton` object.

```
public class PauseButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool firstTimePause;
        private bool checkIfPause;
        public void Awake()
        {
            firstTimePause = false;
        }
        public virtual void PauseButtonAction()
        {
            StartCoroutine(PauseButtonCo());
        }   
        protected virtual IEnumerator PauseButtonCo()
        {
            yield return null;
            checkIfPause = GameObject.Find("SomeObject").GetComponent<GameManager>().Paused;
            if (firstTimePause == false && this.gameObject.name == "ResumeBackground" && checkIfPause == true)
            {
                firstTimePause = true;
                Debug.Log("This is getting printed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have another class trying to access the `firstTimePause` variable on `PauseButton`

```
public class StopWatchTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textTime;

    private PauseButton pauseButtonScript;
    public GameObject pauseButtonObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        pauseButtonScript = pauseButtonObject.GetComponent<PauseButton>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        pauseButtonScript = pauseButtonObject.GetComponent<PauseButton>();
        Debug.Log(pauseButtonScript.firstTimePause); //this value is always false even if it was already set to true on PauseButton Class
        if (pauseButtonScript.firstTimePause == true)
        {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that I always gets False on the variable `firstTimePause` even though I checked that it was set to True by having a Debug.Log

If I changed the class into like this, it is working.

```
public class PauseButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool firstTimePause;
        private bool checkIfPause;
        public void Awake()
        {
            firstTimePause = false;
        }
        public virtual void PauseButtonAction()
        {
            StartCoroutine(PauseButtonCo());
        }   
        protected virtual IEnumerator PauseButtonCo()
        {
            yield return null;
            checkIfPause = GameObject.Find("SomeObject").GetComponent<GameManager>().Paused;
                firstTimePause = true;
                Debug.Log("This is getting printed");
        }
    }
```

This means there is something wrong on the statement `this.gameObject.name == "ResumeBackground" && checkIfPause == true`. But since both scenarios are printing `"This is getting printed"`, I'm getting confused why it won't work as my expectation.

This is SomeObject with GameManager
[image]

Comment: Can you share your GameManager and the object with title "SomeObject"?

Comment: Ok, I will add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Apparently, I have 2 objects that the script is attached.

The first object is where I am setting the variable to become true/false. And checking via Debug.Log shows that it is correctly setting the true/false.

The second object is where I am checking if true/false which always false since it was not being changed. I wanted to thank @Erik Overflow which made me think about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
firstTimePause == false && this.gameObject.name == "ResumeBackground" && checkIfPause == true
{
...
    Debug.Log("This is getting printed");
}
```

> But since both scenarios are printing "This is getting printed"

> Why is it that I always gets False on the variable firstTimePause

This is exactly what you would expect, no? If `firstTimePause` is always false, then you expect the condition above to always be false.

Comment: If I use Debug.Log, `firstTimePause` becomes TRUE. But somehow when I use it on another class, I always get FALSE.

Comment: Can you add that log to your code?